# get image's x y when canvas was scrolled

Tags: canvas, scheme, scrollbar, racket

I am using DrRacket 5.3.4

There is a frame f, canvas c

And I set scrollbar to canvas.

I want to get image's coordinate
(not main window, frame's upper-left-relative coordinate)

how can I get image's x and y?

in short, the scrollbar was moved so I can see image's area whose x and y are from 90, 90 to 290, 290.

at this moment, I move mouse to upper-left corner of the window. and get 0,0.

but I want to get 90,90.

how can I do this?

thanks!

```
#lang racket/gui 
(require racket/draw)
(define f
  (new frame% 
       [label "hey"]
       [width 200]
       [height 200]))
(define img (read-bitmap "some_image.png"))
(define img-w (send img get-width))
(define img-h (send img get-height))

(define (pcb c dc)
  (send dc draw-bitmap img 0 0))
(define my_c%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-event e)

     (printf "x: ~a y: ~a \n" (send e get-x) (send e get-y)))

    (super-new)))
(define c (new my_c%
       [parent f]
       [style (list 'hscroll 'vscroll)]
       [paint-callback pcb]))

(send c init-auto-scrollbars img-w img-h 0 0)       

(send f show #t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
(define my_c%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-event e)
      (let-values (((x y) (send this get-view-start)))
        (printf "x: ~a y: ~a \n" (+ x (send e get-x)) (+ y (send e get-y)))))
    (super-new)))
```

The get-view-start (multi-return-value) property contains the x- and y-offsets for the scrollbar. So adding that to the current x- and y- position gives you the postion on the image. It can give you numbers that are higher than the actual size of the image though, so you'd need to check that against your img-w and img-w values.